# Double error bars for divergent bar charts with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I created a divergent bar chart in R, representing two categories, by making the values of one category negative. However, now I need to add errorbars, but this is not possible as ggplot is obviously now treating these two categories as one bar (just shaded by category). This is my graph and the code to use it:

```
ggplot(fig1, aes(x = species, y = standard.abundance, fill = fire.binary)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = pseudolog10_trans)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/18K7n.png)

I think the only options remaining are either to actually create two graphs and combine them, either with facet_wrap or photoshop. But both options are messy. Is there a package or way to create divergent bar graphs or pyramid graphs, where the categories are counted as separate datapoints and so errorbars could be added? But the structure is still combined together nicely as one?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Your error bars should still work, as long as you add a `group = fire.binary` inside the `aes` of `geom_errorbar`

Comment: Allan's comment worked. I don't know why I ever tried, I assumed there would only be one errorbar per data point. I didn't even need to specify with group = fire.binary in the geom_errorbar part. Thanks!